# How is strong time dilation consistent with weak tidal forces?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, tidal-effect, time-dilation, space-travel

Nolan's latest film, [Interstellar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)), takes pains to explain to lay audience members that the passage of time slows in the presence of strong gravitational fields (as per [Einstein's theory of General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity)). While this certainly makes for an innovative plot device, the way this conceit is portrayed in the film seems inconsistent. Specifically, how can the gravity near [Gargantua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) be so enormous as to produce order-of-magnitude differences in the passage of time, yet at once be so insignificant as to effect the astronauts in no other way whatsoever? At the very least, shouldn't the astronauts be crushed and/or [ripped to shreds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) by [tidal forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force)? How is it that they can saunter around Miller so easily?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/The-Science-Interstellar-Kip-Thorne/dp/0393351378

Comment: Could you address my question specifically in the event that I can't get my hands on the book (assuming it is discussed therein)?

Comment: Gargantua is a fictional supermassive black hole.  From Wikipedia:  *In addition, the tidal forces in the vicinity of the event horizon are significantly weaker for massive black holes. As with density, the tidal force on a body at the event horizon is inversely proportional to the square of the mass: a person on the surface of the Earth and one at the event horizon of a 10 million solar mass black hole experience about the same tidal force between their head and feet.*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermassive_black_hole

Comment: So strong local tidal forces are not entailed by massive block holes? What about the magnitude of the field, would that have an appreciable impact?

Comment: A body in orbit doesn't feel the force of gravity, save tidal forces. That's why astronauts in the ISS are weightless! :)

Comment: @jld I somehow overlooked this obvious point, write up an answer and I'll vote for it.

Comment: No problem. Don't worry about the points, they don't particularly matter to me.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest reason for this is the fact that gravitational time dilation is governed, to leading order (in the zero-spin case for simplicity), by the factor $\sqrt{1 -\frac{2GM}{c^{2}r}}$.  Now, just to make our measurements easier, let's rewrite the mass in terms of the radius of the event horizon:

$$r_{0} = \frac{2GM}{c^{2}}$$

Now, our time dilation factor is: $\sqrt{1 -\frac{r_{0}}{r}}$

Meanwhile, for a head-on course with the black hole, and to leading order, we get that the radial acceleration and the tidal forces are proportional to $\frac{GM}{r^{2}} = \frac{r_{0}c^{2}}{2r^{2}}$.  Note that when $r \rightarrow \infty$, you have the time dilation factor tending toward 1 and the tidal forces tending to zero, as you'd expect.

But, here's the thing.  If I double my distance from the black hole, so $r \rightarrow 2r$, then the force will be reduced by a factor of 4, while the time dilation will be reduced much more slowly ${}^{1}$.  So, this means that it is perfectly possible for time dilation to be a strong effect while tidal forces are still weak, just because the time dilation effect falls off more slowly.

${}^{1}$let's say I go from $2_{r_{0}}$ to $4 r_{0}$, then the time dilation factor will change from $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ to $\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$, for a change factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, which is certainly a much less aggresive factor than dividing by 4.

Comment: Actually (axial) tidal forces fall off as $1/r^3$ to leading order. But that just highlights your point further.

Comment: @jld: yeah, you're right.  I was just pulling "force" in the $r$ direction (you know that, future people reading this might not)

Comment: @JerrySchirmer While I agree with your input and reasoning, the burden of my original question was addressed by jld in that the gravitational force is balanced by the mass-acceleration of the orbiting body—regardless of the strength of the local gravitational field. As long as you are in a physically-possible orbit, it doesn't matter whether you are orbiting the Sun or Gargantua. +1 through for your input.

Comment: Mentioning spin: http://www.wired.com/2014/11/metaphysics-of-interstellar/ Thorne: "I went home, slept on it, did a calculation, and found that if you have a black hole that spins rapidly enough, and a planet that is very close to the last stable circular orbit, you could get the time dilation he wanted. It just amazed me." (Not that it changes your answer, just that in the movie Gargantua is in a stable circular orbit with realistic [but absurd] time dilation)

Answer (score 3):

*time slows in the presence of strong gravitational fields*

It's not the gravitational field that determines time dilation, it's the gravitational potential. The Newtonian approximation really isn't correct here, but let's use it anyway for insight:

- The potential falls off like $1/r$ with distance $r$.
- The field falls off like $1/r^2$.
- Tidal effects go like $1/r^3$.

To get a large potential and small tidal effects, you clearly want a big $r$. That's what you have with a supermassive black hole, since its event horizon is big.